# How to verify the signature (generated by using padding methods) using shell script?

Tags: .net, openssl, cryptography, rsa, sha256

Our server team is generating the signature for the given checksum by using the code below (.net code).

```
Convert.ToBase64String(rsap.SignHash(SHA256.HashData(Convert.FromHexString(strHash)), HashAlgorithmName.SHA256, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1));
```

They are using RSA signature padding.

The checksum we created using sha256 as below

```
sha256sum v.tgz | awk '{printf $1}' > chksum
```

On client side we need to verify the signature using shell script to check if the file is tampered.

I wrote the below shell script to verify the signature generated by server side (.net code)

```
#!/bin/bash

file=$1
signature=$2
public_key=$3

if [[ $# -lt 3 ]] ; then
  echo "Usage: signature_verify <file> <signature> <public_key>"
  exit 1
fi

# Create checksum
sha256sum $file | awk '{printf $1}' > chksum

#decode the signature
cat $signature | openssl base64 -A -d > sign_dec

openssl dgst -sha256 -verify $public_key -signature sign_dec chksum

rm -rf chksum
rm -rf sign_dec
```

But when I ran this script, it is showing as Verification failed. I think I need to pass the padding method when I am trying to verify especially at the step in shell script as below

```
openssl dgst -sha256 -verify $public_key -signature sign_dec chksum
```

But I am not sure how to pass this. Is my assumption correct or can any one please let me know how to fix this issue. (Verified that both client and server are using proper certificates)

Comment: What is `strHash`, the hex encoded message or - as the name implies - the hex encoded hash of the message?

Comment: It is the checksum I generated using 'sha256sum'

Comment: Then `SHA256.HashData(Convert.FromHexString(strHash))` means *double* hashing, is that intended?

Comment: Also, in the *openssl dgst -verify* statement, you probably must not use `chksum` because it contains the hash as hex *string*, but you must pass the *binary* data of the hash.

Comment: I am not sure about that because if I generate the signature using openssl (shell instead of .net code) 'openssl dgst -sha256 -sign private-key chksum | openssl base64 -A > sign_enc' and verify it using the script, verification is succesful.

Comment: The sign statement also hashes twice, which is why verification works. Technically you can do that, it is just not common to hash twice. To verify the .NET signature successfully, you should not use `chksum` (with the hex string) in the openssl statement, but the hex decoded (i.e. binary) data.